# How to pass upstream_http_x_auth_request_email value in a url as query parameter through rewrite

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, oauth2-proxy

I am using oauth2-proxy and nginx for authenticating the request. Below is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ...;
  include ssl/ssl.conf;

  location /oauth2/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4180;
    proxy_set_header Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme                $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $request_uri;
    # or, if you are handling multiple domains:
    # proxy_set_header X-Auth-Request-Redirect $scheme://$host$request_uri;
  }
  location = /oauth2/auth {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:4180;
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme         $scheme;
    # nginx auth_request includes headers but not body
    proxy_set_header Content-Length   "";
    proxy_pass_request_body           off;
  }

  location / {
    auth_request /oauth2/auth;
    error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;

    # pass information via X-User and X-Email headers to backend,
    # requires running with --set-xauthrequest flag
    auth_request_set $user   $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
    auth_request_set $email  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email;
    proxy_set_header X-User  $user;
    proxy_set_header X-Email $email;

    # if you enabled --pass-access-token, this will pass the token to the backend
    auth_request_set $token  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
    proxy_set_header X-Access-Token $token;

    # if you enabled --cookie-refresh, this is needed for it to work with auth_request
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

    proxy_pass http://backend:port;
  }

  location = / {
    auth_request /oauth2/auth;
    error_page 401 = /oauth2/sign_in;

    # pass information via X-User and X-Email headers to backend,
    # requires running with --set-xauthrequest flag
    auth_request_set $user   $upstream_http_x_auth_request_user;
    auth_request_set $email  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email;
    proxy_set_header X-User  $user;
    proxy_set_header X-Email $email;

    # if you enabled --pass-access-token, this will pass the token to the backend
    auth_request_set $token  $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
    proxy_set_header X-Access-Token $token;

    # if you enabled --cookie-refresh, this is needed for it to work with auth_request
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

    proxy_pass http://backend:port;
    rewrite ^ /login?email=$email redirect;
  }
}
```

I am trying to pass the email of the logged in user in the URL , only when request is for '/'.

In access log, I am getting the value of $email, but after rewrite value of $email is blank in URL.

In oauth2-proxy, have enabled header, xAuthRequest, tokens  as below:

```
pass_user_header=true
pass_basic_auth=true
set_xauthrequest=true
set_authorization_header=true
```

I have tried to use $upstream_http_x_auth_request_email, $http_x_email at the place of $email in rewrite block. Bu the result was same.

I also have tried
`set $my_email $email;`

and

`map $email $my_email { default $email; "" $http_x_email; }`
but none of the solution has worked.
I just want to pass the email in the url for that '/' case. rest of the request will be served from default location block.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `access_by_lua`, for that, something like:

```
  access_by_lua_block {
    ngx.redirect("/login?email=" .. ngx.var["email"])
  }
```